# Frozen TextArea Fx While writing in it

Tags: java, javafx

I try to list I big quantity of lines in a TextArea in Java Fx. The problem is that scroll bar frozen and not let me scroll down.  I want to see the last line each time. Or is there another component to show a big quantity of lines. Or do faster this process.

```
        Service<Void> service = new Service<Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Task<Void> createTask() {
                return new Task<Void>() {           
                    @Override
                    protected Void call() throws Exception {

                        File dir = new File("C:\\");
                        int[] count = {0};
                        try {
                            System.out.println("Inicia Visitador de Directorios");
                            Files.walkFileTree(Paths.get(dir.getPath()), new HashSet<FileVisitOption>(),
                                    Integer.MAX_VALUE, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file , BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
//                                          System.out.printf("Visiting file %s\n", file);
                                            ++count[0];
                                            final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
                                            Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {                          
                                                @Override
                                                public void run() {
                                                    try{
                                                        StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer(textAreaLog.getText());
                                                        buf.append(count[0]+" File "+file+"\n");
                                                        textAreaLog.setText(buf.toString());
                                                    }finally{
                                                        latch.countDown();
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            });
                                            try {
                                                latch.await();
                                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                                e.printStackTrace();
                                            }        
                                            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
                                        }

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }


                        //Keep with the background work
                        return null;
                    }
                };
            }
        };
        service.start();
```

Comment: See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What happens if you use `ListView`?

Comment: Try using `textAreaLog.append()` I think it locking up because everytime you "add" too the text area you are completely resetting it in a `Platform.runlater()` the javadoc says "applications should avoid flooding JavaFX with too many pending Runnables. Otherwise, the application may become unresponsive" it takes longer to completely reset the TextArea every time causing the queue to backup causing you to freeze this does not mean the `.append()` will fix the problem it may remedy the issue maybe not

Answer (score 2):

Getting the TextArea to scroll to the bottom is the easy part.  Just use [appendText](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/TextInputControl.html#appendText%28java.lang.String%29) instead of setting the TextArea’s entire text value:

```
textAreaLog.appendText(count[0] + " File " + file + "\n");
```

The bigger problem, as Matt pointed out, is that you’re flooding the JavaFX application thread.  Walking a file tree lists files pretty quickly, and you are sending so many Runnables to the application thread that the thread doesn’t have time to do its normal processing, such as painting the window and handling user input.

There are a few ways to handle this.  A simple approach is to add a sleep call:

```
try {
    latch.await();
    Thread.sleep(200);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Another approach is to create your own buffer, so you will only add the text in large chunks, for instance every 1,000 lines:

```
System.out.println("Inicia Visitador de Directorios");

int maxBufferSize = 1000;
Collection<String> buffer = new ArrayList<>(maxBufferSize);

Files.walkFileTree(dir.toPath(), new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
    @Override
    public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs)
    throws IOException {
        ++count[0];
        buffer.add(count[0] + " File " + file + "\n");

        if (buffer.size() >= maxBufferSize) {
            String lines = String.join("", buffer);
            buffer.clear();

            Platform.runLater(() -> textAreaLog.appendText(lines));
        }

        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }
});

String lines = String.join("", buffer);
Platform.runLater(() -> textAreaLog.appendText(lines));
```